# Error: Unable to retrieve custom url info from APIM Admin API - WSO2 API Manager Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure WSO2 API Manager Analytics. I tried the [Quick Setup](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#quick-setup) locally (it works) and am now attempting the Standard Setup with API Manager in a VM and API Manager Analytics in a separate VM.

But when I access /analytics-dashboard, I get a blank dark screen with the following error:

[image]

The returned error is :

> Error: Unable to retrieve custom url info from APIM Admin API

Any pointers on what could have been misconfigured?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the analytics dashboard server? Please cross check these configs in here - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/master/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/conf/apim-analytics-dashboard/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml#L383

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

1. Open the *<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml* file.
2. Under `properties` section of `auth.configs` add the following property with the value set to APIM url

   `adminServiceBaseUrl: https://localhost:9443`

Comment: Thanks, that did bring me a step closer, my error is now: `No subject alternative names matching IP address XX.XX.XX.XX found executing GET https://XX.XX.XX.XX:9443/api/am/admin/v1/custom-urls/carbon.super` where I was trying to make it work with an internal IP. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out your issue. Simply

- You are using different versions of
- WSO2 API Manager (E.g: wso2am-3.2.0)
- WSO2 APIM Analytics Dashboard and Worker (E.g: wso2am-analytics-3.1.0)

In order to verify if above is the issue you have,

1. Goto deployment.toml of wso2am-analytics: dashboard profile (E.g: /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-analytics-3.1.0/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml)
2. Change following param values of each key value pair of auth.configs:

   ```
   publisherUrl: https://mgt-apim:9443
   devPortalUrl: https://mgt-apim:9443
   ```
3. You should get an error similar to bewlow,

> Exception occurred :No subject alternative DNS name matching mgt-apim found. executing GET https://mgt-apim:9443/api/am/admin/v0.16/custom-urls/carbon.super

Reason for above error is mismatching versions of API Manager and API Manager analytics.

Note: If further help is needed please refer to this sample config,
[sample_wso2_apim_analytics_dashboard.yaml](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/simple/kubernetes-apim-analytics/dashboard/wso2am-pattern-1-analytics-dashboard-conf.yaml)

Comment: Thank you Yasas. I will revisit this in the future when I attempt to integrate Analytics with APIM again