# How To Enable Analytics Dashboard in WSO2 Docker Version?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I did a lot of research on the docs, still when access `/analytics-dashboard` i get `400 Bad Request` error.

i am using **Docker-Compose** version of WSO2 3.2.0, and i have updated the deployment.yaml file

```
[server]

hostname = "check.mydomain.com"

[apim.analytics]

enable = true
```

Is there anything that i missed ?

Comment: Did you follow the standard setup to configure the APIM analytics as in the docs?    https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/

Comment: @chashikajw yes i did, however i am using Docker-Compose version, and i this will not work since we use containers ? or i am wrong ?

Comment: That's not a problem. Did you see any error logs ?

Comment: refer this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855337/error-unable-to-retrieve-custom-url-info-from-apim-admin-api-wso2-api-manager

Comment: @chashikajw thanks for your valuable help, still the same issue, i did `tail -f` on logs and there is no logs at all, see this image for what i see https://imgur.com/a/WVQIVdM , also i just installed a fresh docker-compose wso2 and the same issue happens.